# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Missing Dependency in: SLASensorTune.vi: Library not found or failed to load

Tags: c#, dll, labview

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently facing an issue regarding the invocation of a DLL in different environments, and I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.

The problem arises when attempting to invoke a DLL that was built in LabVIEW 2018 32-bit version from a 32-bit executable developed in VS2022 (C#) on a 32-bit Windows 10 machine. Surprisingly, the DLL invocation works flawlessly in my development environment, which consists of a 64-bit Windows system with LabVIEW 2018 RTE (32-bit) and a 32-bit executable created using Visual Studio.

I am reaching out to seek your expertise and assistance in resolving this matter. If you have any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches that could help me overcome this hurdle, I would be extremely grateful. Feel free to let me know if you need any further information to understand the problem.

Full Error Message

"System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DLL' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Missing Dependency in: SLASensorTune.vi: Library not found or failed to load: LM Numeric Gradient.vi ---> NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.Interop.VIAssemblyException: Missing Dependency in: SLASensorTune.vi: Library not found or failed to load: LM Numeric Gradient.vi"

Upon investigating the differences between the development and production environments, I discovered one significant distinction. In the production environment, the 32-bit RTE is stored in the "C:\Program Files" directory, while in the development environment, it is located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)" directory. In an attempt to resolve the missing library issue, I manually copied the RTE files to the "C:\Program Files (x86)" directory. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.

I'm expecting the Invoking of the DLL should be able to find the library it is missing.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a license issue?

Comment: I do have licenses to NI LabVIEW and VisualStudio on my development machine. My understanding is that for the executable to run on production wouldn't need the license. If for any other reason it is a license issue then how do I know it is a license issue? I haven't received any license error messages.

Comment: The libraries may not be installed or the license is not being found (or both).  Did you check Event Viewer to see if there are more details about the error.  You are getting an INTEROP error.  This may help : https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvhowto/charac_net_interop.html?force_isolation=true  NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.Interop.VIAssemblyException: Missing Dependency in

Comment: Unfortunately there are no errors in the windows event viewer for the missing library issue. I reviewed the link and I did have necessary references in my project; besides the DLL outputs correct data in development environment. It would be nice to find out which NI libraries or DLL has correct references to the LM Numeric Gradient.vi and its libraries. That way I could compare them the DEV and Production environment to make sure necessary files are at right location.

Comment: See following : https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Non-Linear-Lev-Mar-Function-Gradient-Array-Output-of-Function/td-p/898071 and https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/For-quot-Nonlinear-Curve-Fit-vi-quot-what-does-20068-mean-and/td-p/3039553